# How can I un/comment out code in MySQL Workbench using a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: windows, mysql-workbench, keyboard-shortcuts

I went to the official [Workbench keyboard shortcut page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-keys.html) and found this:

> ```
> Function                       | Keyboard Shortcut | Context
> -------------------------------+-------------------+-----------
> Comment/Uncomment lines of SQL |    Modifier+/     | SQL Editor
> ```

However, <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> doesn't work.

I have MySQL Workbench installed on a Windows machine. How do you get the shortcut to work?

Comment: Mid 2018 and this doesn't seem to have been fixed in Workbench. None of my two current keyboards, the one on my Asus laptop and the external Thinkpad keyboard, have a numerical keypad, nor even one that you could select with the keyboard fn or numlock key. It's a trend that I appreciate for several reasons. Is there any way to modify Workbench settings to make `Ctr+/` work?

Comment: @Martin yes, you can edit the `main_menu.xml` to achieve this. Check out my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: I'm using HP laptop(14 inch so not full sized keyboard), mysql workbench 8.0, Ctrl+/  comments the line and Fn + Ctrl + / uncomments the line. Adding this for people who are on same boat and trying to find uncommenting shortcut.

Answer (score 32):

Thanks for filing the bug report, it's annoying.  
If you have a full size keyboard try using the division symbol. 
**i.e.** The CONTROL + "/" using the division key above the keypad instead of the "?/" key on the main keyboard.
It's not nearly as convenient, but it works for me with Windows 7 and MYSQL Workbench 6.1.

Answer (score 19):

Works for me when I press either of the **Ctrl** buttons + **/ ("slash button" in Num Pad)**

Instead you can also simple type "**#**" at the Point of line you want to comment.

- **example:**  `#SELECT * FROM images where category_name = "cars";` comments the whole line

Answer (score 7):

I can confirm that this works on OS X and Linux, but it's failing on Windows. This is likely a bug, please file a bug report at bugs.mysql.com.

Comment: On Mac, it's **comand** + **forward slash** ( **⌘** + **/** )

Comment: On my `MacOS v10.13.3 High Sierra` with `MySQL Workbench v6.3.10`,  *Command + Plus + Forward Slash* ( **⌘** + **+** + **/** ) works

Answer (score 2):

It is now May 2019 and this is still an [open](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68707) issue. There is a work around there but it doesn't work either. Here is what I have done for my `v8.0.15`.

Close MySQL Workbench if you have it open. Find the menu `XML` file at `[path-to-mysql-workbench-folder]\data\main_menu.xml`. Open in any editor and search for `toggle comment`. You should find this menu item:

```xml
<value type="object" struct-name="app.MenuItem" id="com.mysql.wb.menu.edit.
  <link type="object" key="owner" struct-name="app.MenuItem">
    com.mysql.wb.menu.edit.format_menu</link>
  <value type="string" key="accessibilityName">Toggle Comment on Selection</value>
  <value type="string" key="caption">Un/Comment Selection</value>
  <value type="string" key="name">comment</value>
  <value type="string" key="command">plugin:wb.sqlide.comment</value>
  <value type="string" key="itemType">action</value>
  <value type="string" key="shortcut">Modifier+Slash</value>
</value>
```

Change the `key="shortcut"` portion from `Modifier+Slash` to anything that isn't taken, and that does not contain 'Slash' in it. I have it set to `Modifier+Alt+D`. Feel free to set it to what helps you, and try out different combinations if you are having issues. Start up MySQL Workbench and try out your fully working shortcut!

Don't forget you can also manually do this by going to the menu `Edit -> Format -> Un/Comment Selection`. You can also use the division symbol (forward slash) near the full size keypad if you have one. This should work without any changes, but not nearly as convenient.

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered this issue, and came upon this thread.  I found a work around and way to restore the functionality.

It seems when there are more than ond set of dashes ("--") it appends more "--" turns into "-- --"

So i just did a find replace "--" for "".  That reset all my comments and the functionality now works as expected.  (Press "Ctrl+ /" it makes dashes for the highlighted rows, press again and removes them).

Restarting had no effect for me.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience it is NOT / on the number pad but / under the question mark on the key pad, then it works fine

Comment: that's a nice spot!

Answer (score 0):

On my keyboard, in Windows 10, I found to make this work I needed to:

1. select the text to be commented
2. press Fn key
3. press CTRL+/
4. when done, press Fn key

Comment: I have a desktop keyboard, so don't have an `fn` key :(

Comment: Which version of MySQL Workbench are you using? This does not work for me.

Comment: This worked on MySQL Workbench 8.0.16 (Windows 10), Thank You. (Pressing Fn + Ctrl + / while a block of code is selected will comment/un-comment the block as expected. Upon re-opening Workbench Ctrl + / now works as expected). I'v been having this issue for quite some time, now it is fixed!