# How can I comment out code in MySQL Workbench using a keyboard shortcut or menu item?

Tags: mysql, comments, mysql-workbench

The shortcut key Control+/ and Menu (Edit > Format >  Un/Comment Selection) does not work in MySQL Workbench

to reproduce
1. Enter some code in SQL editor / text window
2. select the code
3. Choose Edit > Format >  Un/Comment Selection ( this menu is grayed out)
4. Use the shortcut key  Control+/ ( nothing happens)

Does anyone have suggestions ?  Duplicate of [How can I comment out code in MySQL Workbench using a keyboard shortcut?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27490790/how-can-i-comment-out-code-in-mysql-workbench-using-a-keyboard-shortcut)

Comment: try out the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27490790/how-can-i-comment-out-code-in-mysql-workbench-using-a-keyboard-shortcut/56087431#56087431)

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that this works on ubuntu 14.04 and a MySQL bench version is 6.0.8 build #833.
Make sure that you are using a correct key (near a right shift);
If it still not working then you can change a shortcut key. 
Try to find a main_menu.xml file

```
Linux: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/data/main_menu.xml
MacOs: /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/data/main_menu.xml
Windows: DISK_NAME:\path_to_mysql_workbench\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\data\main_menu.xml
```

Open the main_menu.xml file with your favorit text redactor and find a location of   "comment section". Should looks like:

```
<value type="object" struct-name="app.MenuItem" id="com.mysql.wb.menu.edit.comment">
 <link type="object" key="owner" struct-name="app.MenuItem">com.mysql.wb.menu.edit.format_menu</link>
 <value type="string" key="caption">Un/Comment Selection</value>
 <value type="string" key="name">comment</value>
 <value type="string" key="command">plugin:wb.sqlide.comment</value>
 <value type="string" key="itemType">action</value>
 <value type="string" key="shortcut">Modifier+Slash</value>
</value>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixing Comment / Uncomment feature

If the Menu item is inactive create and install this plugin. If the menu is works but the shortcut is not skip to step 6

1. Create a file with the following code, Filename = comment_grt.py

   ```
   from wb import *

   import grt

   ModuleInfo = DefineModule(name='Comment', author="Scott Hamilton", version='1.0')


   @ModuleInfo.exportFilter("wb.text.comment", "Un/Comment Selection")

   def commentText(text):

     lines = text.split("\n")

     if lines[0].startswith("-- "):

       return "\n".join((line[3:] if line.startswith("-- ") else line) for line in lines)

     else:

       return "\n".join("-- "+line for line in lines)
   ```
2. Install the plugin via menu Scripting > Install Plugin/Module
3. Select the .py file
4. Press open
5. Restart workbench
   Now the Edit > Format Un/Comment Selection menu should be functional
6. If the shortcut does not work, then edit the main_menu.xml file located 
   here - C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\data  (your version / path may vary)

   ```
       <value type="object" struct-name="app.MenuItem" id="com.mysql.wb.menu.edit.comment">

         <link type="object" key="owner" struct-name="app.MenuItem">com.mysql.wb.menu.edit.format_menu</link>

         <value type="string" key="caption">Un/Comment Selection</value>

         <value type="string" key="name">comment</value>

         <value type="string" key="command">plugin:wb.sqlide.comment</value>

         <value type="string" key="itemType">action</value>

         <value type="string" key="shortcut">Modifier+K</value>

       </value>
   ```
7. Change the key after the Modifier+. The default is “Slash” and I changed it to K
8. Restart Workbench again. Also it seems that Modifier+Slash is assigned twice so you could try changing or removing  the definition of the conflicting menu command